# Should I use single or multiple web sockets

Tags: websocket, connection

My server has a C# desktop app that accepts web socket connections from my HTML/JavaScript clients and sends back a stream of images.

Image are each 12kb in size and at least 10 of these are sent to each client every second.

At the moment I use 1 port to handle all my clients.

But, should I use  different port for each connected client instead?

My server is a dedicated server hosted with FastHosts.

Would this be pointless to do as only 1 byte stream can only be sent at anyone time from my server or is the fact that it is a server it can handle many ports at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit in opening different ports for the same thing in the same application. A TCP port is just a way to identify traffic, it is just like a tag.

Comment: What are the drawbacks?  For one, i can think of a limited number of open files (depending on system).  Since the question is for C#, it probably means windows, but could be Mono.  For linux, this eats into the number of open file handles.  Are there others? I'd like to think of it from a mobile device perspective, connect 1 websocket, or multiple... is it really the same less the additional connection overhead?